# Azure PIM Logs Kusto

Tags: azure, log-analytics-workspace

Anyone know where the PIM logs are stored?  I would like to build a query as a part of a alert / logic app.  Basically send the last 24 hours of PIM activations to our ticketing system for a daily security review.  Any examples would be awesome, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to get access to PIM logs outside of the portal. There is a uservoice item [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/39138934-support-diagnostic-settings-for-pim-audit-logs) to enable this.